Data available in standard Shopware Product Export Feed
There is a custom plugin to generate the feed for a product export in XML. I am trying to make the plugin obsolete and do it in the standard Shopware XML template.
The plugin e.g provides data like the categories in text.
The question is if it's possible to retrieve this data too in the XML template standard provided by Shopware for the Product Export Feed.
The IDs of the categories are available in JSON in the standard XML-template Shopware provides:
      "categoryTree": [
        "018ffea6b36773cb869b3a7dd94f369e",
        "a515ae260223466f8e37471d279e6406",
        "8de9b484c54f441c894774e5f57e485c"
      ],


How to get the names of the categories with this ID without extending the Twig template or to make a custom plugin?
